# junit test code is not included in the jar

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit

I am developing 3 projects, projectB and projectC refer to projectA.
I am creating JUnit test code for each of projects A, B, and C. I want to put the common logic used in the tests in projectA, and projectsB and C refer to it.

However, the projectA.jar created by mvn install does not contain any test code.

How do I include test code in the jar?

Comment: The test code normally wouldn’t be in the jar; the jar contains the library. Why do you want the test code in the jar?

Comment: I have created test codes for each of my 3 projects. I don't want to write three identical processes.

Comment: In Gradle I would use the [`java-test-fixtures`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures) plugin to create a source set for this common test utilities. I don't know whether Maven supports a similar feature.

Comment: Resolved. Thanks to everyone who answered!

Answer (score 2):

[This page](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html) has all the details, repeated here as per SO guidelines - **BUT ALSO SEE "The Preferred Way" AT THE END**:

- The Maven Jar plugin has a `test-jar` goal, activate it as usual:

  ```
  <project>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </project>
  ```
- This jar gets deployed with the other artifacts of the project, no extra configuration.
- Use the following ceremony to declare as dependency in test scope of course:

  ```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <classifier>tests</classifier>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <version>version</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  ```

#### The preferred way

Create a separate project/Maven module that has all the reusable test code in the `src/main/` folder, depend on that artifact in test scope.

---

I prefer the preferred way :)